# Why does DDPG/TD3 benefit from old data and PPO not

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have a question of more general kind regarding deep reinforcement learning. I am always a little in struggle, what exactly the difference of on- and off-policy is. Sure one can say, off-policy is sampling from a different distribution for actions during trajectory sampling and on-policy is using the actual policy for trajectory generation. Or on-policy is not able to benefit from old data, while off-policy can. Both do not really answer, what the exact difference is, while rather tell me the output.

In my understanding DDPG and PPO both are build upon A2C and train in parallel an actor and a critic. While the critic usually is trained based on the MSE using the observed reward of the next timestep (maybe using some enrolling for multiple steps, but neglecting an enrollment for now) and the network itself of the next timestep. I do not see a difference between off-policy DDPG and on-policy PPO here (well TD3 does it slightly different, but its neglected for now since the idea is identical).

The actor itself has in both cases a loss-function based on the value generated by the critic. While PPO uses a ratio of the policies to limit the stepsize, DDPG uses the policy the predict the action for the value computed by the critic. Therefore both CURRENT policies are used in the loss function for the critic and actor, in both methods (PPO and DDPG).

So now to my actual question: Why is DDPG able to benefit from old data or rather, why does PPO not benefit from old data. One can argue, that the ratio of the policies in PPO limits the distance between the policies and therefor needs fresh data. But how is A2C on-policy and unable to benefit form old data in comparison to DDPG?

I do understand the difference between Q-learning being far more off-policy than policy learning. But I do not get the difference between those PG methods. Does it only rely on the fact that DDPG is deterministic. Does DDPG has any off-policy correction, which makes it able to profit form old data?

I would be really happy, if someone could bring me closer to understanding those policies.

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

PPO actor-critic objective functions are based on a set of trajectories obtained by running the current policy over T timesteps. After the policy is updated, trajectories generated from old/stale policies are no longer applicable. i.e. it needs to be trained "on-policy".

[Why? Because PPO uses a *stochastic policy* (i.e. a conditional probability distribution of actions given states) and the policy's objective function is based on sampling from trajectories from a probability distribution that depends the current policy's probability distribution (i.e. you need to use the current policy to generate the trajectories)...NOTE #1: this is true for any policy gradients approach using a stochastic policy, not just PPO.]

DDPG/TD3 only needs a single timestep for each actor / critic update (via Bellman equation) and it is straightforward to apply the current deterministic policy to old data tuples (s_t, a_t, r_t, s_t+1). i.e. it is trained "off-policy".

[WHY? Because DDPG/TD3 use a *deterministic policy* and Silver, David, et al. "Deterministic policy gradient algorithms." 2014. proved that the policy's objective function is an expectation value of state trajectories from the Markov Decision Process state transition function...but does not depend on the probability distribution induced by the policy, which after all is deterministic not stochastic.]